# Data event not firing Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube, stream, fs

I'm writing an application that downloads YouTube videos with the extension node-ytdl. I'd like to send the client a progress indicator on the download, so I'm trying to get chunk information to compute it. My code looks kind of like this.

```
        var writing = fs.createWriteStream('video.mp4');
        var stream = ytdl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jofNR_WkoCE', { filter: function(format) { return format.container === 'mp4'; }, quality: "lowest" });
        stream.pipe(writing);

        var completed_len = 0;
        var total_len = 0;

        writing.on('data', function(chunk) {
            console.log('received data!');
            completed_len += chunk.length;
        });

        writing.on('close', function ()
        {
            console.log('close');
            res.send('completed!');
        });
```

Weirdly enough, even though 'close' fires whenever the download is done, I'm not getting any logs from the 'data' event. The video is written correctly. I'm kind of new to Node.js streams. Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've just bound to the wrong stream. `'data'` events will occur on [readable streams](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable), like the `stream` created by `ytdl`.

```
stream.on('data', function (chunk) {
    // ...
});
```

And `'close'` events will occur on both streams if you're using [Node 0.8](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.8.24/api/stream.html#stream_event_close_1) or older. While 0.10 changed the event for writable streams to [`'finish'`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish).

Comment: Do you know where I can get the total chunk length of the stream? I know it should be in the response headers, but I'm not sure how to get that from the stream events.

Comment: @J4G That would probably make for a good post of its own. But, generally, with how you're achieving it now, summing up the individual lengths. Streams on their own don't necessarily have a fixed length when they start, though some implementations might suggest one such as `http.IncomingMessage`s.